# Returning two List<> Objects from WebMethod and Handling them with jQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Stream> GetStream()
{
    List<Stream> Streams = Stream.GetRange(0, 10, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    return Streams;
}
```

I would like this same method to also include the following:

```
List<Comment> Comment = Comment.GetByStreamId(for each stream id 
here of the retrieved streams above);
```

I would also like to return both lists as array of their objects of List so that they are consumed with jQuery ajax.

How can I achieve that and handle them with jQuery after json is returned.

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Comment and Stream has same members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you need to return both Items in a single list 
Then define struct class 
read the values one by one to add into the List

public struct CommentandStream

{

public int Item1;

public int Item2;

}